# Windows 11 install with disable TPM and secureboot option for older computer

Tags: installation, windows-registry, windows-11, tpm, rufus

I try to install Windows11 pro on my old computer which is not meet the minimum requirements for windows 11. It does not have TPM (Trusted Platform Module). So, I try to install with [Rufus 3.17](https://rufus.ie/) with [no TPM and no secureboot option](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/).

There are instructions to install on web without any TPM because there are many computer do not support TPM and secure boot, [an example microsoft site registry edit install](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e#:%7E:text=AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU).

I downloaded Rufus and Win11_English_x64.iso and try to make install usb but Rufus do not show the **disbale TPM and diable secureboot** option. I also checked the web about the Rufus option. Some sites show the older **v3.16beta** work and the newer **v3.17** do not work with no TPM option. I tested both but It does not work.

Since Rufus use [BypassTPMCheck and BypassSecureBootCheck](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#help-i-created-an-extended-media-to-bypass-tpm-but-it-still-says-my-pc-doesnt-support-windows-11) registry keys to bypass the check, it should work. The check depends on registry keys and microsoft thinks there is too much limit to allow only **TPM2.0** and **secureboot enabled** users for windows 11 installation.

Please tell me how to install windows 11 to unsupported computer with no TPM with/without Rufus.

Comment: Best to stay on Windows 10 until you can get a computer that has TPM 2 and a supported processor.

Comment: @John Microsoft states that it can be installed without requiremtns because 2/3 of the users are not meet the requiremetns. The TPM 2.0 and other features can be ignored because they are not strong enough to support security problems with not string encryption standards and maybe only effective on offline hazard environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but Rufus do not show the disbale TPM and diable secureboot option

Most likely because you are running Rufus on Windows 7, which is [no longer officially supported as a platform](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Windows_XP_Windows_Vista_Windows_7_NO_LONGER_SUPPORTED) and where the current method of bypassing the TPM/Secure Boot check can not be applied.

If you run Rufus on any of the supported platforms, and use an official Windows 11 ISO, then the bypass option should be proposed to you.

Also, please be mindful that if you try an in-place upgrade, the registry bypass used by Rufus will not work, [since those keys only work for clean boot](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_I_created_an_extended_media_to_bypass_TPM_but_it_still_says_my_PC_doesnt_support_Windows_11).

> Please tell me how to install windows 11 to unsupported computer with no TPM with/without Rufus.

- Create a bootable Windows drive.
- Boot that drive and once the Windows installer has started, press `Shift`+`F10` to open a command prompt.
- Type `regedit` and create the relevant bypass registry keys (Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig\` and create new DWORD32 registry keys `BypassTPMCheck` and `BypassSecureBootCheck`, setting their value to `1`).

Comment: Rufus did not work since windows 7. I finally installed windows 11 pro on my computer. I made a bootable USB from Microsoft install media. Then, I pressed `shift + f10` and have 'notepad' to open registry edited to bypass tpm, cpu, secureboot, and ram from github.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is like @Akeo's https://superuser.com/a/1699752/157532

You have to prepare the bootable usb pendrive (see *1 below).
In my case (*1) I can write to that pendrive, so I added this file `W11BypassSecureBootAndTPMInstallChecks.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig]
"BypassTPMCheck"=dword:00000001
"BypassSecureBootCheck"=dword:00000001
```

Then you need to click on "recovery" option, then click on "command prompt" and run `regedit` on command prompt and import the .reg file above.
Then you still on the command prompt you run `setup` and continue the installation normally.

(*1) But I only have linux ubuntu, so here is how I got it working:
I use woeUSB-ng on ubuntu to properly write the windows 11 pro ISO file on it. But follow these install instructions (w/o sudo)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342241/1422630

Obs.: I have no idea what rufus is.

Comment: +1 I also recommend this way, because it is minimal invasive to the original installation media and it always works. For (*1) I used the Media Creation Tool from Microsoft directly, which runs on Windows 7/8/8.1 (no longer supported) or Windows 10/11, to create either Windows 10 or 11, depending on which Media Creation Tool you download. Copying one file to it is simple. As for the command prompt when booted from the USB pen drive: just use `Shift` + `F10`. For this one occasion of installing Windows the extra effort having to run regedit should not be too much to ask...